# How to Reference Stylesheet in Custom Masterpage HTML

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, master-page

I have created a custom masterpage HTML page as well as several custom stylesheets for a site in SharePoint online. I have attempted to reference my stylesheets in the HTML page but my styles are not being picked up in the browser. I have tried to reference the css using the following formats within the head tag, none have worked.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="Custom" Name="$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/SiteAssets/search/css/custom.css%" runat="server" After="Themable/corev15.css"/>-->

<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="Custom" Name="https://dynamiconline.sharepoint.com/sites/search/SiteAssets/MarvinSearch/css/custom.css" runat="server" After="Themable/corev15.css"/>-->

<link href="https://dynamiconline.sharepoint.com/sites/search/SiteAssets/MarvinSearch/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction on how I need to format these correctly so my styles will actually come through. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Try the last option ( `<link ...>` ) again but add the closing slash to the end. ie `<link href="/sites/search/SiteAssets/MarvinSearch/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`. The masterfile may be looking for a closing tag that isn't there.

Comment: @KGlasier I appreciate the suggestion, unfortunately I tried this and my stylesheets are still not coming though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/SiteAssets/search/css/custom.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />-->
```

Check the thread below:

[External CSS file in HTML master page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9bc131c3-db38-46b2-992a-abdcf2dac9b0/external-css-file-in-html-master-page?forum=sharepointdevelopment)